# Extracting Original Image name using EXIF

Tags: php, image-processing, exif

So I am trying to find out if an image was renamed or not using PHP. I know this is not reliable, but we are using this only for data mining purposes so it is fine.

Suppose I have an image and I rename it using say Windows Explorer, and not a sophisticated tool that will update exif tags ons such operations.

So in such case when I rename it, will the exif data get updated, or will the Exif Image name tag remain the original name of the image?

Any insight is greatly appreciated. I am planning on using PHP exif_read_tags() to extract the exif info.

Comment: why don't you try it? it's easy enough to just rename a file then view the exif before/after.

Comment: IMHO Exif data is not related to name

Comment: @MarcB: I am currently on the road and thought I might gain some insight before I reach office and head into a meeting. But yes, I intend on trying it out in any case. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @ValeriySolovyov: I am hoping its the same case, I was just wondering if I could catch the attention of anyone who works in this kind of field extensively, who could give me some 'inside data' :) thank you for your comment.

Comment: I renamed files, uploaded them to online photo processing tools and they shown the EXIF metada (GPS, Camera type, etc)

Comment: @ValeriySolovyov: thank you for testing that, is there any exif field that captures the image name, and if yes does it show the original name or the renamed one? thanks once more

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

`exif_read_data()` reads the EXIF headers from a JPEG or TIFF image file. This way you can read meta data generated by digital cameras.

EXIF headers tend to be present in JPEG/TIFF images generated by digital cameras, but **unfortunately each digital camera maker has a different idea of how to actually tag their images, so you can't always rely on a specific Exif header being present**.

There is a chance to read those file parameters:
`FileName`, `FileSize`,`FileDateTime`,`SectionsFound`

You can try this code to read all sections of images:

```
<?php
echo "test1.jpg:<br />\n";
$exif = exif_read_data('tests/test1.jpg', 'IFD0');
echo $exif===false ? "No header data found.<br />\n" : "Image contains headers<br />\n";

$exif = exif_read_data('tests/test2.jpg', 0, true);
echo "test2.jpg:<br />\n";
foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {
    foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
        echo "$key.$name: $val<br />\n";
    }
}
?>
```

The now-defunct EXIF web site referenced above is archived here:
http://web.archive.org/web/20131018091152/http://exif.org/Exif2-2.PDF